# Calculating numeric list with string values

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nan

I have a numeric list with NaN values and I want to apply mathematical functions to it. Also I need keep those NaN values to be stored still after computation

```
list_a = [1827.07, 1376.21, nan, nan, 1001.88, 978.07]
recal_list = []
for i in list_a:
    time = round(i/55)
    recal_list.append(time)
```

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: I want to apply mathematecial formulas to list while keeping NaN values. @mkrieger1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pandas `Series`

```
from pandas import Series
from numpy import nan

list_a = [1827.07, 1376.21, nan, nan, 1001.88, 978.07]
result = round(Series(list_a) / 55)
print(result.tolist())  # [33.0, 25.0, nan, nan, 18.0, 18.0]
```

Or your solution, with an `if`

```
from numpy import nan, isnan

list_a = [1827.07, 1376.21, nan, nan, 1001.88, 978.07]
recal_list = []
for val in list_a:
    recal_list.append(val if isnan(val) else round(val / 55))
print(recal_list)  # [33.0, 25.0, nan, nan, 18.0, 18.0]
```

Comment: Thank you Very Much This What i was Looking For